# bash script which login to many linux servers and execute commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

As in the subject, I would write such a script, but knowing my skills it would be done in a sometimes puzzling way.

**What result do I want to get?**
My script have to connect via ssh to every server from file, and exec just for example
`echo "hello" >> /root/someFile.txt`

**My idea:**
I have a file, where I store data in that way: **hostname:ipadress**

I started writing to go as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

someHello="hello"

for adressIP in $(cat file.txt | awk -F: '{ print $2 }')
    do
        (
            ssh ${adressIP} -t "echo ${someHello} >> /root/tmp"
        )
    done
```

Is it spelled correctly?
Some advices? Tips?

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, it'll probably end up as a triangle.  use [pdsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdsh)

Comment: Start looking into configuration management solutions like `ansible`, `chef`, `puppet`...

Comment: Why does every question asking "I want to run some commands on a bunch of machines" **always** end up with someone saying "use puppet/ansible/chef/etc"?   Sometimes you just want to run some commands on a bunch of machines. Config management tools like puppet etc are a great answer to a very different question.  Not for this question.  And someone struggling with something as simple and straight-forward as this will have not even the slighest hope of setting up something like puppet.

Comment: @cas IMO if you reach the point where your goal is to execute change on multiple machines, you should look into something like that. Yes, cooking up your own solution is possible, but error prone and a waste of time in the long run (reinventing the wheel).

Comment: @Panki You're missing the point.  Executing commands on multiple machines is **NOT THE SAME THING** as using a configuration management tool to manage them.    It's not even the same thing as configuring those remote machines.  Here's a shocking fact: sometimes executing commands on multiple machines has **absolutely nothing at all to do with configuration**.   Simple example: `pdsh -g all 'last username | head'`.   It's almost as if executing commands on multiple machines has more in common with executing commands on one machine than it does with configuration management.  wow, mind-blowing!

Comment: and even when you use a config mgmt tool to configure lots of machines, there will still be many times when it's necessary to just execute some commands on a bunch of those machines.  there will always be times when that is necessary.

Comment: @cas there's no need to be upset. `ansible` does not only do config mgmt, but can also run commands with proper error handling. I can use my existing inventory, do everything in the same "environment". `ansible all -a "last username | head"`

Comment: I'm not upset.  I'm just reacting to your "I have a hammer so everything is a nail" response.   ansible has it's place, as do chef and puppet.  They're all incredibly useful tools if what you need to do is manage the configuration of a large number of mostly identical machines (or sets of different kinds of mostly identical machines).   They also take a lot of planning and work to configure and get working.  A lot more planning and work than is necessary for the simple task of "executing some commands on a bunch of machines". Use the right tool for the job at hand.

Comment: I wrote it in ansible, it went to the servers and everything works fine.

However, I share the opinion of @cas